# Oracle: How to give all privileges of one user to another?

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I have 2 user A and B. They all have some privileges of their own.
Now, i want to give all A's privileges to B.
Is there any way (instantly,...) to do that but write a script to give that grant for each user (by select from USER_SYS_PRIVS - i mean when i have a lot of privileges, it seems impossible to be done!?)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: System privileges could be assigned to a custom role, and the role granted to each user. If there are other table or object privileges they could also be assigned to a role, but depending on how they are used they might still need to be assigned directly (not through a role).

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot grant, for example, `create` privileges on different schema

Comment: this is true: privileges to `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` would only allow USER_B to create or alter their *own* tables, not USER_A's tables. If you wanted USER_B to be able to do things with USER_A's objects, those privileges would have to be assigned explicitly to USER_B, or USER_B would need the corresponding `ANY` system privilege: e.g. `ALTER ANY TABLE`. Assigning the `ANY` privileges comes with risk, because they apply literally to *ANY* object in the database, owned by *ANY* user, including SYS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Get all privileges from AAA

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','AAA') FROM DUAL;

Change the DDL commands with the user 'BBB' and execute.
```

Or

```
expdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=AAA.dmp schemas=AAA

impdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=AAA.dmp
```