# Grant all privs of a user to another user in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a user named A having some privileges. How can I grant all privileges which A is having and grant to user B?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about directly-granted privileges only, or also about roles?

Comment: The same question: [Oracle: How to give all privileges of one user to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72062376/oracle-how-to-give-all-privileges-of-one-user-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all privileges from user A

```
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','A') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','A') FROM DUAL;

 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','A') FROM DUAL;
```

Change the DDL commands with the user 'B' and execute.